# Yii mdmsoft get user ids who have access to specific route

Tags: yii2, yii2-rbac

am using mdmsoft  / yii2-admin plugin is there any way to get user ids who has access/permission to specific route. I need to show only those user who can access the specific action in a dropdown.

Before I was doing this but I want this dynamic based on Helper::checkRoute() method

```
$usersProfiles = UserProfile::find()->all();
$authAssignmentHeadUserIds = AuthAssignment::find()
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'marketing-head'])
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'media-head'])
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'production-head'])
    ->select(['user_id'])
    ->all();

$userHeadProfiles = UserProfile::find()
    ->where(['in', 'user_id', $authAssignmentHeadUserIds])->all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fetch user ids for routes

```
//Getting parent roles which had access to route
$authItemParentRoles = AuthItemChild::find()
    ->where(['child' => '/voucher/accept'])
    ->orWhere(['child' => '/voucher/*'])
    ->select(['parent'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

//Extracting parent role onlys from given array.
$parentRoleArray = array_column($authItemParentRoles, 'parent');

//Extracting user ids whose role is in parent role array
$usersHavingAccess = AuthAssignment::find()
    ->where(['in', 'item_name', $parentRoleArray])
    ->select(['user_id'])->all();

//Lastly fetching profile or users having access to that route.
$userHeadProfiles = UserProfile::find()
    ->where(['in', 'user_id', $usersHavingAccess])->all();
```

Thanks to Shringiraj Dewangan who used array column in his answer, that was the missing piece

Answer (score 1):

**1st method**

Remove **->all()** method and use as **sub query**

```
$subQuery = AuthAssignment::find()
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'marketing-head'])
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'media-head'])
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'production-head'])
    ->select(['user_id']);
    

$userHeadProfiles = UserProfile::find()
    ->where(['in', 'user_id', $subQuery])->all();
```

**2nd method**

get only 1D array for **user id** for condition using **array_column**

```
$authAssignmentHeadUserIds = AuthAssignment::find()
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'marketing-head'])
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'media-head'])
    ->orWhere(['item_name' => 'production-head'])
    ->select(['user_id'])
    ->all();

$userHeadProfiles = UserProfile::find()
    ->where(['in', 'user_id', array_column($authAssignmentHeadUserIds,'user_id')])->all();
```

Comment: is there any way I can make this dynamic?

Comment: Thank's your answer contained a clue, using array_column using which I was able to make it dynamic

Comment: which type of dynamic?

Comment: As mdm uses parent children relations for routing I wanted to fetch parent roles dynamically, sorry the question was outdated.